# $A\cong A^{op}$ means $A$ is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Sorry for my bad English.

Let $A$ be (not necessarily commutative) ring.

By [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_ring), if $A\cong A^{op}$ as ring,  $A$ is commutative, but I cannot proof.

Is this trivial? Please help me.

Comment: Where does it state that? (More to the point, what is $(A \times A^{op})^{op}$?)

Comment: Answering my own question, it never says "if $A \cong A^{op}$ then $A$ is commutative."  The closest it gets to that statement would be interpreted "if $A = A^{op}$, then $A$ is commutative".  This is immediate.

Comment: That Wiki page claims "A ring is commutative if and only if its operation coincides with its opposite operation"... which is a little vague, but "coincides with" is stronger than just "there is an isomorphism". Reading it as "$a\cdot b=b\cdot a$ (for "coincides") is indeed the commutativity. As in the answers, quaternion algebras are always isomorphic to their opposites, ... but _not_ by the identity map.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Indeed, every division algebra that has order two in the Brauer group of its center (such as the quaternions) is a counterexample.

But surely the simplest to grasp counterexample is the matrix ring $R=M_{2\times 2}(\Bbb{R})$. It is not commutative. And taking the transpose, i.e. the mapping
$$A\mapsto A^T$$
is an isomorphism from $R$ to $R^{opp}$ by the known rule $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$.

Comment: Nice, +1........

Answer (score 6):

If $A$ is commutative then trivially $A\cong A^{op}$.

I think that the converse is not true, and I think that the following is a counter example:

Let $\mathbb H$ be the Quaternion algebra. Define
$$
f(i)=i \\
f(j)=k \\
f(k)=j  \\
$$
Then $f$ extends to an isomorphism $f: \mathbb H \to \mathbb H^{opp}$.

Comment: If you want to use the quaternions, a much more natural example is to use the canonical involution, which sends $i$, $j$ and $k$ to their opposite.

Comment: @CaptainLama I agree. Just some thoughts from me: If we view $\mathbb{H}$ as "adjoining a root $j = \sqrt{-1}$ to $\mathbb{C}$" like how $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}[i]$. Then we can write $\mathbb{H} = \mathbb{C}[j] = \{(a + bi) + (c + di)j\}$ where $ij =: k$. Swapping $j$ and $k$ can be thought of as the identity $(a + bi) + (c + di)j = (a + bi) + (d - ci)k$ which is akin to multiplication by $-i$ in the second complex coordinate. That operation is a bit funny.

Comment: Really what you want to do is write a quaternian as a 2x2 matrix over $\mathbb{C}$, $$\begin{pmatrix} a+bi & c + di \\ -c + di & a - bi \end{pmatrix}.$$ Then we can express these isomorphisms as composing the transpose operation and possibly some conjugation (either by a matrix or as complex numbers.)

Answer (score 2):

[This just expands upon my comment, since the answer to the question I asked provides another solution]

Given any ring $A$, the map $$(A\times A^{op})^{op} \to A\times A^{op} : (x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$$
will be a ring isomorphism.  If $A$ were non-commutative, then $B = A \times A^{op}$ is non-commutative but $B^{op} \cong B$.

In particular, if your definition of a ring doesn't require a multiplicative identity, then this is succinctly stated as "Every ring $A$ naturally injects into a ring $B$ such that $B^{op} \cong B$"