# identity map is a ring isomorphism $R \cong R^{op}$ if and only if $R$ is commutative

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

I'd like to show that the identity map is a ring isomorphism $R \cong R^{op}$ if and only if $R$ is commutative.

First suppose that $\operatorname{id}: R \rightarrow R$ is a ring isomorphism from $R$ to $ R^{op}$. Each isomorphism is a homomorphism, hence it  holds that

$\operatorname{id}(a \cdot b)=\operatorname{id}(a) \cdot_{op} \operatorname{id}(b)$ for all $a,b \in R$

Therefore,

$a \cdot b = \operatorname{id}(a \cdot b) = \operatorname{id}(a) \cdot_{op} \operatorname{id}(b) = a \cdot_{op} b = b \cdot a$. Hence, $R$ is commutative.

Now suppose that $R$ is commutative.

Then for all $a,b \in R$ we have that

$a \cdot_{op} b = b \cdot a = a \cdot b$.
Hence, the operations $\cdot$ and $\cdot_{op}$ are the same and since this is the only difference between $R$ and $R_{op}$ we can conclude that $R$ is identical to $R^{op}$

Since $\operatorname{id}: R \rightarrow R$ is an isomorphism, also $\operatorname{id} R \rightarrow R^{op}$ is an isomorphism.

It this proof correct? I feel like my proof is still missing something as it is really short and easy.

Comment: @Randall Now id shall be the automorphism. This makes a difference.

Comment: I see.  I read the title only.

Comment: It is crucial that the isomorphism is given by the identity mapping. Otherwise there are [counterexamples](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4038341/11619)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, and yes, it is that easy.
Here is a shorter way to write it:

Consider $f \colon R \to R^{\rm op}$ given by $f(x)=x$. Then
\begin{align}
\textrm{$f$ is an isomorphism} 
& \iff \textrm{$f$ is a homomorphism} \tag1 \\
& \iff \forall a,b \in R: \ f(a \cdot b) = f(a) \cdot_{\rm op} f(b) \tag2 \\
& \iff \forall a,b \in R: \ a \cdot b = a \cdot_{\rm op} b \\
& \iff \forall a,b \in R: \ a \cdot b = b \cdot a \\
& \iff \textrm{$R$ is commutative}
\end{align}
where $(1)$ holds because $f$ is bijective, and $(2)$ because $f$ is additive.

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind taking a look at my other question which is similar?